# R - replace last instance of a regex match and everything afterwards

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to use a regex to replace the last instance of a phrase (and everything after that phrase, which could be *any* character):

```
stringi::stri_replace_last_regex("_AB:C-_ABCDEF_ABC:45_ABC:454:", "_ABC.*$", "CBA")
```

However, I can't seem to get the refex to function properly:

```
Input: "_AB:C-_ABCDEF_ABC:45_ABC:454:"
Actual output: "_AB:C-CBA"
Desired output: "_AB:C-_ABCDEF_ABC:45_CBA"
```

I have tried gsub() as well but that hasn't worked.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Make the `.*` non-greedy and it should work. `_ABC.*?$`

Comment: Can you give more examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is:

```
sub("(.*)_ABC.*", "\\1_CBA", Input)
[1] "_AB:C-_ABCDEF_ABC:45_CBA"
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at what [`stringi::stri_replace_last_regex`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringi/versions/0.2-5/topics/stri_replace_all_regex) does:

> Replaces with the given replacement string **last substring of the input that matches a regular expression**

What does your `_ABC.*$` pattern match inside `_AB:C-_ABCDEF_ABC:45_ABC:454:`? It matches the *first* `_ABC` (that is right after `C-`) and all the text after to the end of the line (`.*$` grabs 0+ chars other than line break chars to the end of the line). Hence, you only have 1 match, and it is the *last*.

Solutions can be many:

1) Capturing all text before the last occurrence of the pattern and insert the captured value with a replacement backreference (this pattern does not have to be anchored at the end of the string with `$`):

```
sub("(.*)_ABC.*", "\\1_CBA","_AB:C-_ABCDEF_ABC:45_ABC:454:")
```

2) Using a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat) to make sure you only match any char that does not start your pattern up to the end of the string after matching it (this pattern must be anchored at the end of the string with `$`):

```
sub("(?s)_ABC(?:(?!_ABC).)*$", "_CBA","_AB:C-_ABCDEF_ABC:45_ABC:454:", perl=TRUE)
```

Note that this pattern will require `perl=TRUE` argument to be parsed with a PCRE engine with `sub` (or you may use `stringr::str_replace` that is ICU regex library powered and supports lookaheads)

3) A negative lookahead may be used to make sure your pattern does not appear anywhere to the right of your pattern (this pattern does not have to be anchored at the end of the string with `$`):

```
sub("(?s)_ABC(?!.*_ABC).*", "_CBA","_AB:C-_ABCDEF_ABC:45_ABC:454:", perl=TRUE)
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/mSGpHi), all these three lines of code returning `_AB:C-_ABCDEF_ABC:45_CBA`.

Note that `(?s)` in the PCRE patterns is necessary in case your strings may contain a newline (and `.` in a PCRE pattern does not match newline chars by default).

Answer (score 1):

Using `gsub` and back referencing

```
gsub("(.*)ABC.*$", "\\1CBA","_AB:C-_ABCDEF_ABC:45_ABC:454:")
[1] "_AB:C-_ABCDEF_ABC:45_CBA"
```

Answer (score 1):

Arguably the safest thing to do is using a negative lookahead to find the last occurrence:

```
_ABC(?:(?!_ABC).)+$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y4T7jl/3)

```
gsub("_ABC(?:(?!_ABC).)+$", "_CBA","_AB:C-_ABCDEF_ABC:45_ABC:454:", perl=TRUE)
[1] "_AB:C-_ABCDEF_ABC:45_CBA"
```

Comment: Your `(?:.(?!_ABC))+` tempered greedy token is [corrupt](https://regex101.com/r/t8RSQq/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you! I will definitively look where to place the `.` in the future.